# javascript split text into list of words and then dynamically added to div, form tag messing it up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I was testing this code out in an asp.net webform as I am looking to split a text into a list or words in javascript and have each added to its own div.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_split

However in an asp.net webform, the sample code alone produces strange behavior, and the result appears and disappears.  Simply adding the form tags to the online sample reproduces the behavior.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

</form>
```

Is there a workaround for this or alternative ideas to do this in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: _"looking to split a text into a list or words in javascript and have each added to its own div"_ Can include "text" , "list or words" at Question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing is happening because the button is triggering a postback to the server.  This essentially reloads the page which is why it appears as though the text is appearing then disappearing right away.

You can fix this by adding in a `return false;` after `onclick="myfunction()"` like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction();return false;">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var str = "How are you doing today?";
            var res = str.split(" ");
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

However, I do not recommend using the `onclick` attribute to call a JavaScript function as there are better ways to do this.  For the purpose of your example, I provided the simplest solution to the problem, but I want to make you aware that there are better ways to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to Howard Renollet's explanation for the form behavior:

A `<button>` element has different `types`. [W3Schools mentions that "different browsers may use different default types for the  element."](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

When in a form, the `submit` and `reset` types will actually do things to the form! In order to put a button into a form without it submitting the form, set the type to `button`:

```
<form>
  <button type="button">Yay, I won't submit this form!</button>
</form>
```